# Convert Extended Stored Procedure to User-defined Function

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, dll, user-defined-functions

I have a .dll which have attached to SQL Server using an extended stored procedure.

Is there any way to use the dll in a function?

Comment: What does your extended stored procedure do? Functions in SQL Server aren't allowed to change database state, e.g. you cannot insert or delete or anything like that.

Comment: I wanted to use Extended SP in a cross apply like FN